# Generic constraints in Kotlin, is this simply a variance problem?

Tags: generics, kotlin, interface

I have a bit of a problem with creating some abstractions in my project written in Kotlin. Let's say I have an interface

```
interface IInterface<A : Any, B> where B : IInterface<A, B> {
    fun doSomething(someData: A): B
}
```

Everything I care about the type B is that it implements the IInterface and is returned by the doSomething function of this interface. The first obvious choice is to provide B as a generic parameter.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
class MyClass<A : Any, B>(val value: String) : IInterface<A, B> where B : MyClass<A, B> {
    override fun doSomething(someData: A): B = MyClass(someData.toString())
}
```

where the overriden function returns an object of type which is constrained to the type of the class itself.

Unfortunately for some reason the compilier complains that the return value of the overriden function is not B but MyClass even if I rectricted B to be of type the MyClass.
Am I missing something? Any variance magic maybe?

There is probably a legitimate reason for that which I'm not seing. But how to approach this?

The other problem I'll most likely face is the constructor which will be used outside the Myclass instance.

`val aMyClassInstance = MyClass<A, ??? >( "a value" )`

I guess this could be done the Scala way with some help from Arrow library  but first I would like to find out if a no-cheating Kotlin solution is possible.

Comment: Your signature means that your method needs to return a specific subclass of MyClass, where the B type variable identifies that subclass. What your method actually returns is an instance of MyClass, not the specific subclass required by the signature.

Comment: @yole Not sure if I understand this correctly but in the `where` clause I specify 'where B : MyClass<A, B>'. Does that mean that in this context MyClass is not considered a subclass of itself?

Comment: No, it is subclass of itself, that's not the problem. The signature allows you to instantiate MyClass with a subclass of MyClass as the B type parameter. In that case, you'd have a method that is required to return a subclass of MyClass but returns simply MyClass.

Comment: @yole so, since I know B must inherit from MyClass, In order to solve my problem I should snly need cast B to MyClass? `override fun doSomething(someData: A) : B = MyClass<A,B>(someData.toString()) as B' . Unless I've got this completly wrong...

Comment: I think you should have written this instead: `class MyClass<A : Any>(val value: String) : IInterface<A, MyClass<A>> {
    override fun doSomething(someData: A): MyClass<A> = MyClass(someData.toString())
}`

Comment: @yole, this is the thing I wasn't able to see! thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

That is a known problem, you may vote for 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17186

As a workaround, you'd need to declare an inheritor of MyClass that substitutes all type parameters. It will allow to solve your problem.